# Adding count(*) from group and cte to variable?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The contents of table `@sales` is basically the most sold car brand per city. This is saying that *Toyota* was sold the most in *Houston* and *Chicago*, etc.

The result of this query (which I *know* can be better) shows what brands were tied and the amount of times it tied. For example, *Chevy* tied for 1st place in two cities, *Ford* tied in one city (Miami), and so on.

How can I add `count(*)` to the variable based on `CarSoldMost`? In this case, I would add `2` to `@chevy`, 1 to `@ford`, etc?

I was thinking of using a `case` statement, but it's being used incorrectly.

```
declare @toyota int = 0
declare @nissan int = 0
declare @chevy int = 0
declare @ford int = 0

declare @sales table
(
    city varchar(10),
    CarSoldMost varchar(10)
)
insert into @Sales
select 'Chicago', 'Toyota' union
select 'Orlando', 'Nissan' union
select 'miami', 'Ford' union
select 'miami', 'Chevy' union
select 'houston', 'Toyota' union
select 'houston', 'Chevy'

select *From @sales


;with cte as 
(
    select city
    from @sales
    group by city
    having count(*) > 1
) --select carsoldmost, count(*) from @sales where city in (select city from cte) 
group by carsoldmost
select @chevy = 
case 
    when carsoldmost = 'chevy' then @chevy+count(*)
    when carsoldmost = 'Ford' then @ford+count(*)
  end
from @sales where city in (select city from cte) group by carsoldmost

select @chevy, @ford
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignments to variables need to be done with separate `case` *expressions*:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Sales as Table(
  City VarChar(10),
  CarSoldMost VarChar(10) );
insert into @Sales ( City, CarSoldMost ) values
  ( 'Chicago', 'Toyota' ),
  ( 'Orlando', 'Nissan' ),
  ( 'Miami', 'Ford' ),
  ( 'Miami', 'Chevy' ),
  ( 'Houston', 'Toyota' ),
  ( 'Houston', 'Chevy' );
select * from @Sales;

-- Summary variables.
declare @Chevy int = 0, @Ford int = 0, @Nissan int = 0, @Toyota int = 0;

-- Summary query.
with cte as (
  select City
    from @Sales
    group by City
    having Count(*) > 1 )
  select
    @Chevy += case when CarSoldMost = 'Chevy' then Count(*) else 0 end,
    @Ford += case when CarSoldMost = 'Ford' then Count(*) else 0 end,
    @Nissan += case when CarSoldMost = 'Nissan' then Count(*) else 0 end,
    @Toyota += case when CarSoldMost = 'Toyota' then Count(*) else 0 end
    from @Sales
    where City in ( select City from cte )
    group by CarSoldMost;

-- Display the results.
select @Chevy as 'Chevy', @ford as 'Ford', @Nissan as 'Nissan', @Toyota as 'Toyota';
```

Answer (score 0):

additional variant to already posted using conditional agregation

```
-- display result/or replace aliasis by variables to assign values.
select 
  Chevy = Count(case when CarSoldMost = 'Chevy' then 1 end) ,
  Ford = Count(case when CarSoldMost = 'Ford' then 1 end),
  Nissan = Count(case when CarSoldMost = 'Nissan' then 1 end),
  Toyota = Count(case when CarSoldMost = 'Toyota' then 1 end)
from @Sales as a
Where City in (select City 
               from @Sales
               group by City
               having count(City)>1)
```

testing:

[image]